# Looking for maven archetype for objectify + gwtp

Tags: google-app-engine, maven, objectify, gwt-platform, maven-archetype

Looking for the maven archetype/template for google app engine Objectify + google web toolkit Platform. ( We don't need any Spring code. )

We need a version that can work immediately to build, compile, debug locally and to upload to app engine.

It needs to be able to generate eclipse (Indigo) project file and to be imported to eclipse trouble-free.

Comment: And what exact problem do you have?

Comment: cannot find one that satisfy the requirements. None works. The problems were too complicated to ask individually....

Comment: I think you have to start doing it, step by step. Every specified techology is compatible with maven, have examples for maven, and can be tied w/o problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at http://code.google.com/p/gwtgae2011/source/browse/pom.xml. Not sure if it will work but I started using that one and then fixed the issues I had. It's not perfect but I can develop in Eclipse with my fixed pom file.

Comment: This is the best answer ever I got on SO. saved me tons of time!!

Answer (score 3):

This is a late answer but a good one I think :

https://github.com/ArcBees/ArcBees-tools/tree/master/archetypes/gwtp-appengine-objectify

Answer (score 0):

You can use this http://www.kindleit.net/maven_gae_plugin/examples/index.html as a reference. It has Objectify and GWT specific examples (separate types though).

I know the Objectify version works, though it will require a bit of tweaking to meet your specific needs. The gae.version used was kind of old, but no problem switching it 1.6.0.